# Are there more examples/samples/tutorials of viewpagerindicator around?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I've been googling non-stop to try and wrap my head around this. No matter what I do I just can't get it to work.

I can get a simple pageradapter that returns a different xml layout, but I just can't figure out how to do the same with viewpagerindicator.

I've been going through the sample but mass of code doesn't really help without explanation of what it does.

The nearest I've found to explanation is [this](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537), but that seems to be pretty outdated from what I can tell.

NB. I am a beginner to android development.

Answer (score 4):

Jake Wharton has provided *a lot* of [**sample code**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) on how to use his library properly. In my opinion, it's the best reference on the internet.